# Calculate the number of times a value changes within a collection

Tags: java, java-stream

For example suppose i have a list of objects

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
            {
                add(Integer.valueOf(1));
                add(Integer.valueOf(1));
                add(Integer.valueOf(2)); // changed
                add(Integer.valueOf(2));
                add(Integer.valueOf(2));
                add(Integer.valueOf(3)); // changed
                add(Integer.valueOf(3));
                add(Integer.valueOf(1)); // changed
                add(Integer.valueOf(2)); // changed
            }
        };
```

The above example should return the number 4 as the value has differed from the previous number 4 times.

i presently have a cumbersome and difficult to maintain way that involves looping through the item and keeping track of the previous value and an accumulator to store the number of transitions.

I'm interested to see if there's a java 8 streams way to solve this problem, or a more elegant solution than simply trudging through the collection and maintaining copies of the previous value.

Thanks!

Comment: **Do not use double bracket init. Ever!**

Answer (score 3):

Just compare an element to the preceding element:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < integers.size(); ++i) {
  if (!integers.get(i).equals(integers.get(i-1))) {
    ++count;
  }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

or, using an `Iterator`:

```
int count = 0;
if (!integers.isEmpty()) {
  Iterator<?> it = integers.iterator();
  Object prev = it.next();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object curr = it.next();
    if (!curr.equals(prev)) {
      ++count;
    }
    prev = curr;
  }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: this is exactly what i'm doing presently. I was looking for alternatives to this solution.

Comment: Why do you think you need alternatives? What is it that you're trying to optimize for?

Comment: "maintaining copies" there are no copies being made here. It's just references to existing objects. "trudging through the list" given that you need to look at every element in turn, there's not much else you can do.

Comment: If you want to ''streamify" your first solution, you can do `long count = IntStream.range(0, integers.size()-1).filter(i -> !integers.get(i).equals(integers.get(i+1))).count();` which would be an equivalent. (P.S: I took the liberty to edit your answer, there was a right parenthesis missing in the first snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using a reduce operations. However I wouldn't ever write code like this as this is hardly more readable than the iterative solution. The Java Stream APIs aren't designed to be stateful with operations across elements, so don't ever use this code.

```
 static class ReduceContext {
    public final Integer previous;
    public final Integer result;

    public ReduceContext(Integer previous, Integer result) {
      this.previous = previous;
      this.result = result;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2);

    ReduceContext reduction = list.stream().reduce(
        new ReduceContext(null, null),
        (ctx, current) -> current.equals(ctx.previous) ? ctx : 
              new ReduceContext(current, ctx.result != null ? ctx.result + 1 : 0), 
        (x, y) -> new ReduceContext(null, x.result + y.result));

    System.out.println(reduction.result); // prints 4
  }
```

The trick is to reduce over a context that is keep getting updated if the previous value differs from the current streamed element. Also this implementation would be broken with parallel reductions, which also has some nasty edge cases on the combiner.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. There are stateful `Stream` operations, such as `distinct` and `sorted` - they're just tricky to write is all.

Comment: @BoristheSpider if ordering of the input comes into play like in this case, writing combiners is not easy- that's all I wanted to convey. Combining sets or sorted lists is trivial because they do not depend on the input order.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a standard List that's fine, but if you want to use some Java 8 try out the ObservableList.  With my example below I did not make it geared towards being able to add in an entire list of values at once, but a single value at a time.

```
ObservableList<Integer> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer> c) -> {
        while( c.next() ) {
            if( c.wasAdded() ) {
                // Make sure the list is not equal to 1, or you'll compare a null and get an error
                // Then get the added sub list (the new value you're adding) and compare it to the second to last
                if( c.getList().size() > 1 && c.getAddedSubList().get(0) != c.getList().get( c.getTo()-2 ) ) {
                    System.out.println( "Change!" );
                }
            }
        }
    });

list.add( 1 );
list.add( 1 );
list.add( 2 );
list.add( 3 );
list.add( 1 );
list.add( 2 );
list.add( 3 );
list.add( 3 );
```

Output:

```
Change!
Change!
Change!
Change!
Change!
```